# Goodness of fit test for a normal distribution

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

In the example from the web site I was trying out [this problem](http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/alevel/fstats_ch5.pdf) 
in **page 107** about Goodness of fit test for  a normal distribution.Question is about analysis of fat content of hamburgers.

I understand that  we need to have the two intervals **-$\infty$< x< 26** and   **$40< x<$$\infty$** to find the class probabilities of intervals  26< x <28 and
38< x<40.
But why should the **expected frequencies of the two intervals  -$\infty$< x< 26** and **$40< x<$$\infty$** be also **calculated and used for chi Squared value**. 
These two categories are **not** there in the given data set.

Is it necessary to break our intervals such that they start from -infinity and end from infinity as this is a normal distribution?

Comment: Suppose there were *no* observations in one of the middle categories--say, in the interval $(32,34]$. That would be a glaring departure from a Normal distribution, wouldn't it? So should you or should you not include that interval in your calculation?

Comment: I think that should be included and since expected frequency is less than 5, then it should be combined and create a common  category (30,34]

Comment: You're right that it's because of the normal distribution being on $(-\infty,\infty)$. They're included because if the data are actually normal, those classes are possible... they just had observed frequency zero in the sample. You divide the continuous null distribution up to compute the expecteds, not the observed distribution. If you exclude those classes your test doesn't have the desired properties. Incidentally, the chi-square test has *terrible* power as a test of normality. If you come to edit your question, you might like to fix the typo in 'hamburger'.

Comment: Now its "hamburger". Thanks for the explanation.So even for a Poisson distribution, say for example the variable x is the number of malfunctions per model and the given data set has values for x=0,1,2,3,4,5 when applying chi squared test since Poisson is valid for all positive values of x, we should include the category x>=6 right?

Comment: Too late to fix "its" to "it's". Chi-squared for Poisson would indeed typically include an open-ended category: in your example the observed frequency would be 0 in the last category and the expected frequency would be whatever it was. That's definitely part of the evidence and you need the sum of the expected frequencies to equal the sum of the observed frequencies.

Comment: In my lecture however the lecturer didn't consider the category x>=6.There the observed frequency was 100 and the total of  expected frequency was 99.777.But the test statistic was computed by simply taking 100 as expected frequency and didn't have the category x>=6.

Comment: Then your lecturer was wrong. The neglected term may not make much difference in practice, but it should be there. Also, 7 cells and 6 d.f.